# Rename columns by pattern in R

Tags: r, rename, renaming

I would like to rename all my columns in a dataframe by a specific pattern.

My input:

```
Log.NE122  Log.NE244  Log.NE144
-0.33       0.98        1.0
```

My expected output:

```
 NE122  NE244  NE144
-0.33   0.98    1.0
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to change the `colnames()` of an object. Here I'm replacing the Log. with nothing:

```
colnames(object) <- sub("Log\\.", "", colnames(object))
```